# Duplicate account with same email

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, customer-account

I notice on Magento 1.7.0.2 and 1.9.2.4, some customer accounts which are duplicated.

However one is defined on the default store view (id: 1 => "Default Store View") and the second one is defined on "Admin" (id: 0 => "Admin").

The store view "Admin" is not visible from magento backend but exist in database.

What is this?
How it possible?
What does this means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is this? How it possible? What does this means?

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but this was a problem in older magento versions when you have created customers from backend (maybe only when create new order with new customer?) they were assigned to storeview ID 0.

This was an discussed here [Create backorder + new customer gives customer associated to admin](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/issues/359), but it seems to be fixed with magento 1.9.3.x.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent this by changing the following configuration option:

System > Configuration > Customer Configuration > Account Sharing Options > Share Customer Accounts

This option is now probably set to 'Per Website' at your shop, when you set it to 'Global', just one account per email address can be created, shop-wide.

The customers that are created at the 'Admin' level are probably created via the admin, possibly by creating orders via the backend.